# wget localhost - connection refused - Atlassian Installation on AWS

Tags: networking, server, firewall, wget, aws

I am trying to debug why I get a connection error when trying to setup Confluence on an AWS Instance.

I tried to do a simple test command on the CLI and got an error "Connection Refused" which makes me think perhaps its a Ubuntu Firewall issue, but I disabled UFW and it doesn't seem to have FirewallD. What other culprits/things could I try to disable/configure?

```
root@confluence:/usr/src# wget http://localhost:8090
--2018-05-16 01:03:37--  http://localhost:8090/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8090... failed: Connection refused.

root@confluence:/usr/src# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            990         191         145          11         653         627
Swap:             0           0           0

root@confluence:/usr/src# systemctl status confluence
● confluence.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/confluence; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2018-05-16 01:03:25 UTC; 1min 3s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 22595 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/confluence start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 16 01:03:25 confluence confluence[22595]: To run Confluence in the foreground, start the server with start-confluence.sh -fg
May 16 01:03:25 confluence confluence[22595]: executing using dedicated user: confluence
May 16 01:03:25 confluence runuser[22602]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user confluence by (uid=0)
May 16 01:03:25 confluence confluence[22595]: If you encounter issues starting up Confluence, please see the Installation guide at http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DO
May 16 01:03:25 confluence confluence[22595]: Server startup logs are located in /opt/atlassian/confluence/logs/catalina.out
May 16 01:03:25 confluence confluence[22595]: Existing PID file found during start.
May 16 01:03:25 confluence confluence[22595]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
May 16 01:03:25 confluence confluence[22595]: Tomcat started.
May 16 01:03:25 confluence runuser[22602]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user confluence
May 16 01:03:25 confluence systemd[1]: Started confluence.service.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a low powered server. I literally had to leave it over night and it was working the next day. I'm not 100% sure this was the issue but please try that approach.